# set the dependent keys of a computed property at run time

Tags: ember.js

Here is the scenario

```
dep = function(){

     cannot put any "this" here
}

obj =  DS.Model.extend({
        response: DS.attr(),
        cp: Ember.computed(dep(), function(){ ...})
    });
```

the computed property is known only after the model has loaded ; the response is a json field, containing various keys. I want dependency on parts of the json, what exact part is known after the model is loaded

the dep() function would need to have access to "this" but it does not work if it is defined outside the create instruction, and it does not work if it is defined as a computed property either
for instance

```
obj =  DS.Model.extend({
    response: DS.attr(),
    dep:Ember.computed('response', function(){ 
     some computation 
     and for instance 
     return 'response.path1{a,b}';
     }),
    cp: Ember.computed('dep', function(){ ...})
});
```

does not work either because dep is not changing from just 'response' dependency, we would need to apply the same dependency on cp and dep which is tautological, and dep would not be needed

Another thing that does not work is

```
  obj =  DS.Model.extend({
            response: DS.attr(),
            cp: Ember.computed(this.dep(), function(){ ...}),
            dep(){    this.get('response')...  }
        });
```

So does any one knows how to set the dependent keys of a computed property at run time, with a computation dependent on a Model instance

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In computed property dependent key, can only be `string` or any global function which return `string` but you can't access `this` context inside function.

I would recommend to move `cp` from `Model` to some other.

In model ready hook, you can create dynamic computed property and set dependent key from `response`.

May be the below code will help you to find solution. I haven't done like this, may be you can give a try.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.Model.extend({
    response: DS.attr(),
    ready() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        var response = this.get('response');
        //you can write dep() logic here and contstruct dynamic key . You will have access to this context here.
        var newDynamicKey = 'response.path1{a,b}';
        Ember.defineProperty(this, 'cp', Ember.computed(newDynamicKey, function() {
            //do your work and return result
            return 'result';
        }));
    }
});
```

Comment: by the way you can put a function call in place of the dependent key of the computed property provided the call has no arguments and returns a string. I tried it first and it worked, but when I needed to pass an argument for this function it did not work anymore

Comment: @user2725682 Yes. you are right..I updated my answers. If required you please review my answers with your implemented solution.